# Importing from different directories in Python

Tags: python, django, web-scraping, scrapy, importerror

I'm trying to build a very simple Web Scraper that scrapes from popular Job Boards and posts the jobs in a simple Django website.
In my Scrapy spider, I am trying to create a Django model object for every job scraped. But I'm having trouble importing the model in my Scrapy spider file.

This is my folder structure:

```
F:.
│   db.sqlite3
│   manage.py
│
├───jobs_board
│       asgi.py
│       settings.py
│       urls.py
│       wsgi.py
│       __init__.py
│
├───main
│   │   admin.py
│   │   apps.py
│   │   models.py
│   │   tests.py
│   │   urls.py
│   │   views.py
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   ├───migrations
│   │       0001_initial.py
│   │       __init__.py
│   │
│   └───templates
│       └───main
│               home.html
│
└───scraper
    │   scrapy.cfg
    │   t.py
    │   testing.md
    │
    └───scraper
        │   items.py
        │   middlewares.py
        │   pipelines.py
        │   settings.py
        │   __init__.py
        │
        └───spiders
                indeed.py
                __init__.py
```

What I want to do is, if I run the spider "indeed.py", I want it to be able to import the main/models.py file. How would I achieve this?

Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: How are you running the `indeed.py` script? If the script needs access to your apps models then changing it to a custom management command would probably make things easier since you won't have to manually initialise Django https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you using anything like the `pathlib` or `os` modules?

Comment: @hrokr No, I'm not. Should I be doing that?

Comment: @IainShelvington I'm using the "scrapy crawl" command from the terminal.

Comment: Yes, you need to look up how to manage the Python path variable in your operating system.

Comment: @Hassan - yes, you need to. Give me a sec and I'll put something a bit more complete together for you. Or, if that's enough of a hint, we can leave it at that.

Comment: @hrokr Sorry, I still haven't been able to fix this issue. Is there some way to import modules using the os or pathlib modules? Or some other way to import the "main" module in my case...